# OpenSSL how to Disable and/or Uninstall

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https, openssl

I installed OpenSSL on the Apache/RHEL and now I will have certified SSL 'Trusted Root CA' and will install it. So I need to disable or uninstall OpenSSL.

How can I:

- Disable the OpenSSL?
- Uninstall the OpenSSL?

Comment: Just to clarify - by "certified SSL" you mean an SSL Certificate that you want to use put the website under? I.e. use https:// ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly - you don't need to unistall OpenSSL.

Comment: You have not acquired a 'certified SSL trusted root CA', unless you are a certificate authority yourself, in which case you would know better than to ask this question. You have acquired a certified signed by a trusted CA, and that does not imply that you can now dispense with OpenSSL. You can't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have no idea why you think acquiring a signed certificate implies that you need to uninstall OpenSSL, but whatever your reason, you are mistaken. It doesn't. Leave it alone. You need it.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on how you installed it to begin with.

```
sudo yum remove openssl
```

Should work.  But you might need to find the exact name of the package that was installed. To search on your local system for the package do this:

```
rpm -qa | grep openssl
```

And then `yum remove` the exact named package you have installed.

Or you can search the repository for all packages named `openssl` or a variant.

```
sudo yum search openssl
```

Comment: And then what good is his certificate to him?